# How to return int array in C using this Collatz Conjecture function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

### I have a function for the Collatz Conjecture that returns an int Array but I keep getting a segmentation fault error and am not sure why.

```
int n=1;  

int* col fuction(int x){
    int *totalList;

    totalList[0]=x;

    while (x != 1){
        if (x%2==0){
            x=x/2;
        }else{
            x= 3* x + 1;
        }

        totalList[n]= x;
        n++;
    } 
    totalList[n+1]=1;
    return totalList;
}
```

It is suppose to return the integers in a row with commas in between each number. I call it as shown below:

```
    int *colAns;
    colAns= col(num);
    for (int k =0; k< n; k++){
        printf("%d", colAns[k]);
        if(colAns[k] != 1){
            printf(",");
        } 
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Comment: `totalList[0] = x` runs with an uninitialized pointer `totalList`.

Comment: As a side not, you should turn on compiler warnings with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`, as they should be able to warn you about problems like this where you are trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: use `malloc` to allocate memory for `totalList`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies within the first few lines of `col_function()`.

```
int* col_fuction(int x){
    int *totalList;

    totalList[0]=x;
    // ...
}
```

When the `int*` called `totalList` gets created on the stack, it takes whatever value was previously there. There's a slim chance that the pointer value will be anything even owned by the process, let alone something valid/usable.

What you need is a dynamically-allocated value that can grow as values are added to it. For this, we use `malloc` to allocate a pre-determined amount of memory. Because the collatz function is recursive and the number of elements cannot be determined by merely looking at it, we cannot presume to know exactly how much memory it will take, so it should grow as numbers are added to it. For this, we use `realloc`. What's nice about `realloc` is that, if the first parameter is NULL, it is guaranteed by the standard to work like `malloc`.

The only other thing you really need is a couple of `size_t` values inside of a struct in order to keep track of the current index as well as the allocated space. Something like this should be sufficient:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE 100

typedef struct dynarray
{
    int *values;
    size_t allocated, used;
} dynarray;

int dynarray_init(dynarray *d)
{
    memset(d, 0, sizeof(dynarray));
    return 0;
}

int dynarray_deinit(dynarray *d)
{
    free(d->values);
    memset(d, 0, sizeof(dynarray));
    return 0;
}

int dynarray_append(dynarray *d, int val)
{
    int *tmp = NULL;
    size_t i;
    if(d->used + 1 >= d->allocated)
    {
        if((tmp = (int*)realloc(d->values, (d->allocated + CHUNK_SIZE)*sizeof(int))) == NULL)
        {
            perror("realloc() failure");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            d->values = tmp;
            d->allocated += CHUNK_SIZE;
        }
    }
    d->values[d->used++] = val;
}
```

Use `dynarray_append()` to add values to the list after it's been initialized.